# Cannot find a resource for cookbook on ubuntu version 14.04

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use chef-solo to make a VM have a particular hostname.  It seems chef has a feature to include other people's recipes in your own which contain complex logic to account for edgecase scenarios such as hostname.sh being removed from platforms.  I get the below error when trying to use chef-solo to apply my recipe.

```
NameError
---------
Cannot find a resource for cookbook on ubuntu version 14.04


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /home/vagrant/chef/cookbooks/op/recipes/default.rb:17:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/home/vagrant/chef/cookbooks/op/recipes/default.rb:

 10:  # username is pretty fragile...
 11:  username = File.basename(Dir['/home/*'].first)
 12:  
 13:  file '/etc/motd' do
 14:    content "#{hostname}\n\nThis server does: \n-Dokku"
 15:  end
 16:  
 17>> cookbook 'hostname', '~> 0.4.0'
 18:  
 19:  default_attributes :set_fqdn => '*.project-domain.com'
 20:
```

Here are the complete contents of the recipe I'm trying to configure:
(chef/cookbooks/op/recipes/default.rb)

```
# --- Install packages we need ---
package 'ntp'
package 'sysstat'
package 'git'

# --- Set host name ---
# Note how this is plain Ruby code, so we can define variables to
# DRY up our code:
hostname = 'epd-dokku.local'
# username is pretty fragile...
username = File.basename(Dir['/home/*'].first)

file '/etc/motd' do
  content "#{hostname}\n\nThis server does: \n-Dokku"
end

cookbook 'hostname', '~> 0.4.0'

default_attributes :set_fqdn => '*.project-domain.com'

# file '/etc/hostname' do
#   content "#{hostname}\n"
# end
#
# service 'hostname.sh' do
#   action :restart
# end

file '/etc/hosts' do
  content "127.0.0.1 localhost #{hostname}\n"
end


#########################
# Put dotfiles in place #
#########################

git "#{ENV['HOME']}/dotfiles" do
  repository "https://github.com/my_gh_name/dotfiles.git"
  action :checkout
end

# you still need to run ./make.sh as the actual non-root user acct though...
execute "#{ENV['HOME']}/dotfiles/make.sh" do
  # user username
  cwd "#{ENV['HOME']}/dotfiles"
end

["#{ENV['HOME']}/.this_machine", "/home/#{username}/.this_machine"].each do |this_machine_path|
  file this_machine_path do
    content "bash_display_style=server"
  end
end
```

I have a suspicion that the code required to use hostname must be different from what I have currently.

```
cookbook 'hostname', '~> 0.4.0'

default_attributes :set_fqdn => '*.project-domain.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on assigning dependencies and including recipes can be found in the documentation for recipes.

The "Manage a basic web application" tutorial (https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/ubuntu/) includes a step where you assign a dependency on another cookbook and use a recipe from that cookbook in your own cookbook.  Check out part three of that tutorial, "Ensure the apt cache is up to date."

I've created a simple cookbook that includes the hostname cookbook and uses its default recipe in my own cookbook - https://github.com/nathenharvey/my_hostname

-Nathen

Answer (score 0):

The `cookbook 'hostname', '~> 0.4.0'` line belongs in your `metadata.rb`, not in a recipe. Similarly `default_attributes` is something you would set in a role, not a recipe. I think you're trying to mix and match APIs from different contexts.

Comment: Thanks!  I think you're almost definitely right.  I'm learning from http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/06/chef-solo-tutorial-managing-a-single-server-with-chef/ which does mention a recipe (I think) but not metadata.rb.  Do you have a link to a repo somewhere with a good metadata.rb to help indicate where I put the file in relation to my recipe and what kind of structure a valid metadata.rb file must take on?

Comment: Try starting over from https://learn.chef.io/, that's our actual tutorial. In the future, try not using educational materials from 2011 ;-)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't think you understand how many people are disenfranchised by the inadequacy of the official docs for Chef.  It's a different experience learning Chef from your co-workers and also glancing at the docks vs learning primarily from said docks.  That you don't even know where to point specifically within your own docs to address this SO question is a quite telling indicator that something's gone wrong at Chef.  Thx for the down vote, nice touch...

Comment: I wasn't the one to vote you down (I rarely vote on questions to start with, I look at too many to care one way or another), nor do I work for Chef Software. I just run volunteer user support because Chef is so bad at it. So yeah, you're welcome to use 5 year old tutorials, but I can't help fix things there. If you want better support, try the IRC channel or Slack teams, I watch both closely.